# Default save location when viewing a PDF from a web page via Internet Explorer

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer

When viewing a `PDF` from a web page via `Internet Explorer`, the default save location is the Desktop.

Where can I change the default save location?

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: It is version 11.

Comment: How are you viewing the pdf? With 3rd party software?

Comment: Just the standard PDF Add-In like everybody uses.

Comment: Do you have to use IE? If not Firefox uses the default "Save to location" for PDF downloads if you use the inbuilt PDF viewer "Preview in Firefox"  within options->applications instead of Adobe Reader/DC or whatever version you have. This allows you to open a preview of a PDF and then Ctrl-S to save to whatever location you have set for downloads. Using Adobe reader to view PDF's appears to complicate things.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Adobe Reader, it appears there is no option to change the default location as it leaches off IE's default-save location (as its an add-on) or your last save location. Best you could do is change your IE default save location :(

http://blog.chron.com/helpline/2006/10/changing-the-default-save-location/
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/797451

Comment: Incorrect. The default save location for PDFs does not use the IE default save location.